# Change String date format and set into TextView in Android?

Tags: android, android-date, android-dateutils

I want to change my date format that is in as

```
String date ="29/07/13";
```

But it is showing me the error of ****Unparseable date: "29/07/2013"*** (at offset 2)*
I want to get  date in this format 29 Jul 2013.

Here is my code that i am using to change the format.

```
tripDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tripDate);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
            try {
                oneWayTripDate = df.parse(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tripDate.setText(oneWayTripDate.toString());
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try like this:

```
String date ="29/07/13";
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
try {
    oneWayTripDate = input.parse(date);                 // parse input 
    tripDate.setText(output.format(oneWayTripDate));    // format output
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It's a 2-step process: you first need to parse the existing String into a Date object. Then you need to format the Date object into a new String.

Answer (score 7):

Change the format string to `MM/dd/yyyy`, while `parse()` and use `dd MMM yyyy` while `format()`.

Sample :

```
String str ="29/07/2013";
// parse the String "29/07/2013" to a java.util.Date object
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(str);
// format the java.util.Date object to the desired format
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd / MM / yyyy, HH:mm");
String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```